# RAW data POST API using curl not working but executing in POSTMAN is okay

Tags: php, curl, slim

I am a beginner in PHP and I am trying to put POST data using cURL. I tried in Postman my data and it returns

[image]

but when I execute this code below which I found here in StackOverflow `response` returns me a `307 Temporary Redirect`.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://mycustomURL.com/api/v1/login" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     '{
    "loginid":"test",
    "password":"111111"

}' ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/raw')); 

$result=curl_exec ($ch);


var_dump($result);
```

Can you help me what is the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make cURL follow a redirect just add this line:

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

for more info see [php.net curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: Thank you! you saved me for hours